# Need to allow an action method string parameter to have markup bound to it

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action method that takes in a string as its only parameter.  The action method transforms it, and returns the result back to the client (this is done on an ajax call).  I need to allow markup in the string value.  In the past, I've done this by decorating the property on my model with `[AllowHtml]`, but that attribute cannot be used on a parameter and the `AllowHtmlAttribute` class is sealed, so I cannot inherit from it.  I currently have a work around where I've created a model with just one property and decorated it with the aforementioned attribute, and this is working.

I don't think I should have to jump through that hoop.  Is there something I'm missing, or should I make a request to the MVC team to allow this attribute to be used on method parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at `ValidateInputAttribute`? More info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/11/09/mvc3-granular-request-validation-update.aspx.

Comment: It would be much nicer if there was a per parameter attribute, that way you can be extremely granular on which fields are allowed to have potentially unsafe values, but for my needs at this time, this does the trick, thanks!

Comment: This doesn't help when you need to allow HTML in just one parameter of many.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to allow html input for a particular **parameter** (opposed to "model property") there's no built-in way to do that because `[AllowHtml]` only works with models. But you can easily achieve this using a custom model binder:

```
public ActionResult AddBlogPost(int id, [ModelBinder(typeof(AllowHtmlBinder))] string html)
{
    //...
}
```

The AllowHtmlBinder code:

```
public class AllowHtmlBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var name = bindingContext.ModelName;
        return request.Unvalidated[name]; //magic happens here
    }
}
```

Find the complete source code and the explanation in my blog post: https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/273-aspnet-mvc-allowing-html-for-particular-action-parameters/